# Notation for the composite function

Tags: notation, function-and-relation-composition

Teaching in the UK, I have noticed that all the exam boards (OCR, Edexcel, AQA, MEI) the following notation for functions and composite function.

1. Functions are written in roman upshape (e.g. $\mathrm{f} : A \to B$, $y = \mathrm{g}(x)$, etc.) rather than in italic.
2. If $\mathrm{f}$ and $\mathrm{g}$ are functions, the composite function is written as $\mathrm{gf}(x) = \mathrm{g}(\mathrm{f}(x))$.

Apart from the exam boards, and the textbooks endorsed by the exam boards, however, this is actually the first time I see this notation, for **all** my undergraduate and graduate book use the notation $g\circ f$ to denote the composite function, defined as $(g \circ f)(x) = g(f(x))$. I have tried to look up for any reference of usage of this confusing notation, which many of my students keep confusing with the product of two functions, but I have not been able to find any undergraduate/graduate textbook using this notation. So, my questions are:

1. Do you know any textbook using this notation, and if so, can you please give me the reference?
2. Is there a particular reason why someone should use the notation $\mathrm{g}\mathrm{f}$ instead of $g \circ f$ to denote the composite function?

Generally mathematicians coming from different experiences have different taste for notation, but this is not like the upshape vs italic 'd' in an integral or in the derivative, that is evenly distributed between those who use one and those who use another: I actually have not been able to find a single reference, beside Wikipedia, mentioning the notation (as $gf$ rather than $\mathrm{gf}$), but quoting a book that actually uses the notation $g\circ f$.

Thank you to whoever has any information that might help me understand the choice of the exam boards. (Bu the way, I have tried to question the exam board, but my query has remained unanswered.)

Comment: I'm from Singapore and have taken the Cambridge (UK-based curriculum) exams like the GCE O and A levels. So my math curriculum used the $gf$ notation for composition but I also recall seeing the $g \circ f$ notation somewhere along the way, maybe in the same texts. I'm ok with either as long as there is a proper definition provided before use, and there's something to be said for the brevity of $gf$. Besides there is no one universal convention for all this, and plenty of abuse of notation with functions - tell me why $\sin^2 x$ means square of sine but $\sin^{-1} x$ doesn't mean reciprocal.

Comment: Yup, I can read both too and yes, mathematics doesn't have universal notations, but some are more common than others, and I literally have never seen used the notation without the circle anywhere else, but with the UK exam boards. My real nuisance is that I don't understand the reason of this unusual choice. Let's draw a line under $\sin^{-1} x$ it is simply nonsensical.

Comment: It is false that this notation cannot be observed outside the context of the UK exam board. You mentioned wikipedia but that wiki article (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition) under "alternative notations" does provide a motivation (group theory) and a book reference https://books.google.nl/books?id=z7EHBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA217&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: Thank you, but I cannot see the book you listed as the content seems to be protected. Anyhow, I will go from there. I have never said that the notation cannot be observed outside the UK exam board. I said i have never seen outside it... clearly except for linear operators, in which not only do I generally say $AB$ to say $A \circ B$, but I do not use the brackets too. So for a linear operator $(A\circ B)(x)$ becomes simply $ABx$, or, more likely, $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}\mathbf{x}$, as I generally use boldface for matrices and vectors.

Comment: Right here: https://ibb.co/GdDhSmy To be fair, that was prefatory to a group theoretic proof, so those conventions were used, but it's not worth splitting hairs about this kind of thing in my opinion. The most important thing if that the meaning must be unambiguous *in context* and that comes from defining it before usage, as I've already stated.

Comment: Tilting at the windmills of overextended math notations and conventions will not lead to anything fruitful. People will still argue about the careless way the exponents of trigonometric functions are used (as I cited before), there will still be contention about whether "$\log x$" refers to base $e$, base $10$ or base $2$ and there will still be trolling videos featuring mathematical expressions designed to exploit the weaknesses of different conventions in something as basic as the order of arithmetic operations. There's no sense in any of this. Anyway, I've said my piece. Peace out.